# Removing parts of filenames in Powershell from a file list

Tags: powershell, scripting, rename, file-handling

I have a bunch of directories with files in them and my goal is to loop through a directory structure and write each of the files one by one to a new location.
The files on disk look like this:

```
    - DATAFILE1_DATE_20210101_RUNDATE_20210101.csv
    - DATAFILE1_DATE_20210102_RUNDATE_20210102.csv
    - DATEFILE2_DATE_20210103_RUNDATE_20210103.json
    - DATEFILE2_DATE_20210104_RUNDATE_20210104.json
```

I'm trying to pass the contents of the directory to a variable `$fileSystemItems` and then to remove everything after `_DATE` so that I could build a new directory structure in the target as:

```
    - /target/DATAFILE1/DATAFILE1_DATE_20210101_RUNDATE_20210101.csv
    - /target/DATAFILE1/DATAFILE1_DATE_20210102_RUNDATE_20210102.csv
    - /target/DATAFILE2/DATEFILE2_DATE_20210103_RUNDATE_20210103.json
    - /target/DATAFILE2/DATEFILE2_DATE_20210104_RUNDATE_20210104.json
```

The PS code I have so far takes the files from a specified directory and outputs them:

```
    $sourcePath = "\\files\data"
    $fileSystemItems = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }

    foreach ($file in $fileSystemItems) {
    Write-Host "Writing name of the file is $($file.BaseName)"
    }
```

I have tried using the `Rename-Item` and regex but renaming the files the source is not an option as other programs are accessing the same data, for example:

```
    Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "^_DATE+","" }
```

How do I modify the filename in the `$file` variable in the `foreach` loop to output both a edited version of the file name (e.g. **DATEFILE1**) and also the full file name **DATAFILE1_DATE_20210101_RUNDATE_20210101.csv** ?

Comment: But where in your second example (what the new structure should look like) are the files renamed? This is not really clear to me.. If you remove everything that comes after `_DATE`, you would end up with files that all have the same name giving naming collisions, so Windows would not allow it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rename-Item` is a great tool to begin with! First, let's optimize your code snippet a little bit:

Instead of piping `Get-ChildItem`s output to `Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }`,  we'll use the `-File` switch.

Let's also change your regex from `^_DATE+` to `_DATE.*` and use a pipeline with ForEach-Object:

```
Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.Fullname -NewName (($_.Name -replace "_DATE.*","") + $_.Extension)
}
```

Looking at your destination structure it looks like you might also want to move files to a `target` directory.